# Calling View present in HomeController from Action Method of otherController

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

Can anyone please help me? I am trying to call a view which is present in **Home Controller** directly from the action method of another controller. I don't want to use the `return redirectToAction()` method, but rather would like to call the view of `HomeController` directly. In `HomeController` I have this HttpGet Method:

```
 public ActionResult SuperAdmin()
    {
        if (Session["User"] != null)
        {
            TempData["BindGrid"] = objDBContext.tbl_Student.Where(X => X.RegistrationConfirmed == false).ToList();
            return View(); //Go to SuperAdmin View if condition is true
        }
        else
        {
            return View("Login", "Home"); //else redirect to Login view
        }
    }
```

**Present Controller** from where i would like to call HomeController **SuperAdmin** View

```
public ActionResult Search(string Search)
    {
        if (Session["User"] != null)
        {
            if (Search != string.Empty)
            {
                TempData["BindGrid"] = objDBContext.tbl_Student.Where(X => (X.UserName.StartsWith(Search) || Search == null) && (X.RegistrationConfirmed == false));
            }
            return View("SuperAdmin", "Home"); //If true, go to SuperAdmin view directly               
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Home");
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can use:  return RedirectToAction("SuperAdmin", "Home");

Comment: No direct way, instead of calling action method?

Answer (score 0):

You can directly return a different view like:

```
return View("yourViewName", Model); //if it is in same controller and if you pass model then pass model in this way
```

if your view is in different controller then

```
return View("FolderName/ViewName", Model ); // pass a view of a different controller with model. Just specify view name and it's folder name
```

Comment: But it will either look this view in Present Controller or else in Shared Folder! But my view is present in Home Controller. So it will throw 404: Resource not found Error/Exception

Comment: add a directory of view page in return View("folderNameofController/ViewPage"). If controller is CustomerController and action is index then index view will be created in Customer folder inside views folder. So, enter the correct directory of view page with view name